# Turn off auto focus in android

Tags: android, camera

It is any way to turn off auto focus in camera in code my application. I want to check how my scanner work if phone has no auto focus, but in my phone I have that function.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`FOCUS_MODE_INFINITY`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#FOCUS_MODE_INFINITY) or `FOCUS_MODE_FIXED`. You can also use `FOCUS_MODE_MACRO`, but that will require holding your phone quite close to the object you're scanning.

On a second thought, the word 'scanner' evokes thoughts of barcodes and QR codes, so unless you print them as full-size page, you actually might be better off with `FOCUS_MODE_MACRO`.

You can set the desired focus mode with [`Camera.Parameters.setFocusMode()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setFocusMode%28java.lang.String%29) when opening your camera.

Comment: I am super frustrated with Android camera access. One reason is that they have deprecated so much of it and what I tend to find online is for the deprecated APIs -- not for current tech. So, do you know what the answer to the question is today?

Answer (score 0):

You Can use `mCamera.cancelAutoFocus();`

Also if you want to set Macro or another Focus Mode, you shall write:

```
Camera.Parameters mParam = mCamera.getParameters();
mParam.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_MACRO);
mCamera.setParameters(mParam);
```

All the focus mode and Camera parameters are availble [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html):

Comment: What is mCamera here?