# How to disable any focus in camera in Android

Tags: java, android, android-camera

I am developing an app and one of the features of this app is making photos. I noticed that on some devices it takes too much time for camera to make a shot because of autofocus. I tried to change different focus modes  in Camera.Parameters but still have no success. I also noticed that some apps, like b612 for example are taking photo within a second. How they are doing this? How can i programmatically turn-off any focus to make shots very-very fast?

Comment: Can check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14580281/turn-off-auto-focus-in-android

Comment: Thanx, bro! But this didn't help me. Taking a photo still takes too much time((

Comment: Did you find any solution? @bukka.wh